# expire cookie - magical number -86400

Tags: php, cookies

I'm reviewing the code of my framework which deletes cookie on client and here is the piece of code where it does it:

`return setcookie($name, NULL, -86400, Cookie::$path, Cookie::$domain, Cookie::$secure, Cookie::$httponly);`

I'm particularly interested in why the number is `-86400` seconds? Is it just random number or it has any special meaning in some convention? I can expire cookie with `-1`, can't I?

Comment: Have you tried to calculate how many minutes and hours it is?

Comment: @zerkms, I guess you are the one who downvoted :). If you read the question attentively you'd see that I don't ask about how many hours it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-86400 seconds is exactly a day ago. But that aside, I don't think it has any special meaning. Maybe the guy writing this chose this value to also wipe cookies for browsers that are in a different timezone or of people that have their computer clock set to a slightly incorrect time.

But my guess would be that there used to be 86400 (as a positive number), and the programmer just made it negative to remember the old value, in case they would need it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one does make sense - _Maybe the guy writing this chose this value to also wipe cookies for browsers that are in a different timezone or of people that have their computer clock set to a slightly incorrect time._. What number do you use to expire cookie on client side? And I didn't understand this one _there used to be 86400 (as a positive number), and the programmer just made it negative to remember the old value, in case they would need it again_ - could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: That last part is just a guess, but I can imagine how the ttl for cookies would have been 1 day before. Then they need to be cleared and the easiest way is just to put a `-` in front of the number, also so you can restore it later. But then later never comes, and the number remains in the code, causing you to ask this question. I've seen stuff like that, although I cannot prove it is what has happened here. :)

Comment: Got you, thanks!  What number do you use to expire cookie on client side?